# how to create an apa regression table in r using coefficients from linear and moderated regressions

Tags: r, linear-regression, coefficients

i have run a simple linear regression and 2 moderated regressions and need to present a coefficients table for each. I have tried a few different bits of code I've found on the internet but none produce a table similar to what is shown as an example regression table on the apa website. They have to be in APA format and ideally able to be downloaded straight to a word doc.
my simple linear regression is:

```
DF1 <- lm(formula = UEBscore ~ TUTscore, data = finalised_dataset) 
summary(DF1)
```

and my 2 moderated regressions are:

```
DF2 <- lm(TUTscore~social_context * UEBscore, data = finalised_dataset) 
summary(DF2)
```

```
DF3 <- lm(TUTscore~emotionality* UEBscore, data = finalised_dataset) 
summary(DF3)
```

I want a code that produces a table in APA format using the coefficient output I see from my regressions in R. I am not entirely sure of what is supposed to be in these tables but so far from the APA template and other resources I've gathered I should have my estimate, SE, t value, p value, CI and R squared for intercept and TUTscore and potentially also f stat and b value (b value does not show on my regressions output in R)

the only code I have found that works is this which is saved and able to open up in a word doc in APA format but it only includes *b*, *b* 95% CI, *sr2*, *sr2*95% CI and Fit - I don't know if these conf ints are different to what is produced when you run a regression in r but the numbers don't match up to the coefficients output I get when I run the regressions normally and are missing estimate, SE and p value which are on the APA sample regression table

```
library(apaTables)
table1 <- apa.reg.table(DF1, table.number = 1)
apa.reg.table(DF1, filename = "table1.doc")
```

I have tried to use this code but it is saying it doesnt recognise apa.save

```
library(apaTables)
table1 <- apa.reg.table(DF1, 
                        table.number = 1)
apa.save(filename = "table1.doc", 
         table1)
flextable::save_as_docx()
```

and tried this code but nice_table isnt recognised

```
install.packages("rempsyc")
install.packages("flextable")
pkgs <- c("flextable", "broom", "report", "effectsize")
install.packages(pkgs)
library(rempsyc)
table1 <- nice_table(
  DF1[1:3, ], 
  title = c("Table 1", "Linear Regression Between TUT and UEB"), 
  note = c("The data was extracted from my study", "* p < .05, ** p < .01, *** p < .001"
  )
)
```

Comment: try `rempsyc::nice_table()` in case there is some conflict with your other packages

Answer (score 0):

The documentation appears to be for the development version not the CRAN version. [In an open issue on GitHub](https://github.com/dstanley4/apaTables/issues/40), the package developer suggests this:

```
apa.reg.table(blk1,filename="exRegTable.doc")
```

However, you may be better served by installing the GitHub development version:

```
library(devtools) 
install_github("dstanley4/apaTables")
```